# create-react-app proxy setting in package.json not working

Tags: reactjs, proxy, fetch, create-react-app, package.json

I'm trying to use the proxy field in package.json to proxy my fetch calls to aws api gateway endpoint. I've tried million of ways and still it's not working.
my setup is:

```
"proxy": {
"/DEV/*": {
  "target": "https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  "secure": false
}
```

}

I also tried  other 1000 combinations (secure to true , changeOrigin or /DEV) and also:

```
 "proxy":  "https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
```

even I tried restart my pc :) 
my call is:

```
return fetch('/DEV/servers', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'session': getState().authReducer.auth.session
        }
```

unfortunately no success, still it tries to call http://localhost:9000/DEV/servers
wonder if I needed to do something else first which I haven't done.
Thanks

Comment: the call to localhost is correct. that's what the proxy is for. or do you mean that your webpack dev server is trying to call itself

Comment: if you want to make a call directly to your aws url then instead of a proxy you want to use an environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after one day I found out :((

it was the corporate proxy of our company... basically I had proxy on my browser but not on webpack so at some point I tested localhost and I saw that it's working.
then I tried with internet without any proxy (vpn) and it worked